# How to add value to Page Slug in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

My problem with the Page slug in wordpress I'am created **new page**, slug name is `star`
now the link for this page is `http://localhost/star/` it works when I'am get into it 
I want make this page accept another argument => the star name 
 to make the link like this `http://localhost/star/hisham-mohamed`  
 to get this name and get all posts for him, but when I get into it redirect me to *404 Error* .

Comment: Of course it will give you error the way routing work in WordPress. I suggest you to read documentation about permalinks in wordpress. Here is the one of the way you can handle above situation. 1. Create custom post type which is 'star' (or whatever you want). 2. Then the name of star will be as post under star. then your permalinks chnage to : site.com/sample-post.  Just think how you can handle this with custom post type

Comment: iam search to mach but nothing benefit me , i want to know if there a function do what i want becuase have `star` , `writer` and `director` i want to make pages for all this include argument => `person-name`